# Updated less files, not showing up after page refreshes

Tags: node.js, less, ghost, gruntfile

As the subject states, I have made some minor CSS updates via one of the LESS files on a Ghost theme but when I refresh I don't see the changes reflected. I'm assuming since I'm new to LESS and node that perhaps I'm missing compiling LESS to convert it and save the CSS output. Is this like a "watch" task I need to add to a gruntfile? I'm trying to understand how is that all these work together.

Answer (score 0):

For those as me new to LESS and facing similar issue, I found this article really helpful http://ericnish.io/blog/compile-less-files-with-grunt/ after some reading I was able to update LESS files and see the results on css styles and the site.